# Why given real and manually deflated series are not same in FRED?

Tags: time-series

when I deflate a series (for specific example, take M1 (M1SL) series from FRED) by CPI, it is not exactly the same as the one the that FRED provides i.e. M1REAL. It seems like M1REAL is a scaled up series with respect to the series obtained by M1/CPI. Any idea, why that is the case? They should exactly be the same.

Comment: You might want to add some details (what CPI data series used), method / formula applied etc. Otherwise anyone looking at this can just guess what you might be doing.

Answer (score 0):

FRED's *M1REAL* variable is the variable *M1SL* deflated to '82/'84 dollars by the series *CPIAUCSL*.  You are right in understanding this identity.

Dividing *M1SL* by *CPIAUCSL* gives a series very close to *M1REAL*, with a maximum monthly deviation of 0.0498, or just under $50 million (less than 0.000001% of M1 in 01/2024), in the time period from 1980 to 2023.  These deviations are either due to rounding of the versions of the variables published on FRED, or to rounding of the variables themselves; the largest deviations between *M1REAL* and its calculated equivalent occurred during the 1980s, when precision matched the analytical methods employed at the time.